# Duplicate Desktop Icons for single user over Remote Desktop Session

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, rds

We have an RDS environment for our customers where they RDP into their server and their AppData is stored in a remote profile disk (VHDX), their user home is a redirected folder also stored in a remote location. Some customers have more than 1 RDS session host they can connect to, this one in particular has 2.

With one user in particular, ***only one*** user, 3 of their desktop shortcuts are duplicated. If I check their redirected folder stored on the remote server, there are a copy of the desktop icons which there should not be. All icons needed by users are stored in the Public Desktop. If I delete the duplicated icons for that user, next log on they appear again.

We tried:

- recreating their AppData VHDX
- ran Windows Updates
- deleting the duplicate icons
- move the user to another RDS session host
- perform full sign out and sign in

I tried to do some research on it and only found registry key fixes or scenarios that are different than what we're experiencing. My issue with the registry fix is that the user is using RDP so its not a local issue, plus the issue is happening regardless on what server they log into. This tells me that the issue is tied to the user account rather than the server. And any registry key editing could also affect other users which we don't want to happen.

Aside from that, we're kind of out of ideas and want to leave migrating the user to a different account as a last resort.

Anyone have any ideas? Maybe there's a known bug for this? The session hosts are running Windows Server 2016, some are Windows Server 2019.

Comment: Do you also use roaming profile? The desktop might accidentally also be part of it. Or might these shortcuts be created by a gpo or login script?